# Dynamically Change Css Styles in C# (Sharp) Without Asp

Tags: c#

Hi all hopefully this is a quick one.
I'm working on a c# web browser that, amongst other things, changes css styles of web pages like google and facebook. for example it will make the background on facebook and google red instead of white. i've had success but its not at all consistent and i have no idea why.

```
HtmlDocument doc = Browser1.Document;
HtmlElement textElem = doc.CreateElement("DIV");
textElem.InnerHtml = "<STYLE>body{background-color:red!important}</STYLE>";
doc.Body.AppendChild(textElem);
```

that code works on www.google.com but not www.rationality.tk however..

```
HtmlElement head = Browser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0];
head.SetAttribute("bgcolor", "red");
```

That  code works on [www.rationality.tk](http://rationality.tk) but not [www.google.com](http://google.com) and both codes do not work on www.facebook.com which i cannot get anything to work on.

I'm probably doing something wrong and I just moved on to c# after giving up on c++ and I have found it a lot easier but still getting the hang of it. thank you in advance.

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

```
HtmlElement head = Browser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0];
head.Style = "background-color:red";
```

this works on facebook, google and rationality.tk

Comment: Even Chrome's dynamic style editing is inconsistent.

Comment: i just dont understand google has a body so why doesnt the set attribute work as for rationality.tk it has no preset css styles could that be why setting the css editing code doesn't work. and i am utterly lost with facebook i can't even edit specific divs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but the problem might be due to embedded `iframes` and igoogle like widgets. I have faced the same problem while implementing a similar functionality in COM/ATL for my Browser Helper Object. The approach that helped me (to some extent) was to wait for `DOCUMENT_COMPLETE` event for each `iframe` and then try to get their `body`. Again I am not sure how you can achieve the same in C#. This is just some food for your thoughts.

Comment: I am very very pleased to announce that i have fixed the problem by pure fluke here is my code and have posted the solution in my post